# Nodejs fails on `new <something>` declaration?

Tags: node.js, jsdom

I have a js function working perfect when **on client side**:

```
// [...] (some meta lines here)
var converterEngine = function (input) { // BLOB => Binary => Base64
    var uInt8Array = new Uint8Array(input),
          i = uInt8Array.length;
    var biStr = []; //new Array(i);
    while (i--) { biStr[i] = String.fromCharCode(uInt8Array[i]);  }
    var base64 = window.btoa(biStr.join(''));
    return base64;
};
// less important but complementary
var getImageBase64 = function (url, callback) {
    // to comment better
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(url), img64;
    xhr.open('GET', url, true); // url is the url of a PNG/JPG image.
    xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
    xhr.callback = callback;
    xhr.onload  = function(){
        img64 = converterEngine(this.response); // convert BLOB to base64
        this.callback(null,img64); // callback : err, data
    };
    xhr.onerror = function(){ callback('B64 ERROR', null); };
    xhr.send();
};
```

On nodejs side, the code is loaded and used via `node myscript.js` such:

```
var jsdom = require('jsdom');
var fs    = require('fs');

jsdom.env(
  "<html><body></body></html>",        // CREATE DOM HOOK:
  [ '../js/b64.js' ],                 // ... & offline

  function (err, window) {
   window.getImageBase64("http://bip.bop/img.png", function(err,data){
              //doing more funny stuff here
           })
  }
);
```

**When ran via node**, nodejs script fails on the `new` with a `TypeError: Type error`:

```
file:///data/yug/projects_active/make-modules/js/b64.js:9
    var uInt8Array = new Uint8Array(input),
                     ^
TypeError: Type error
    at converterEngine (file:///data/yug/projects_active/make-modules/js/b64.js:9:22)
    at xhr.onload (file:///data/yug/projects_active/make-modules/js/b64.js:24:17)
    at dispatchEvent (/data/yug/projects_active/make-modules/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/xmlhttprequest/lib/XMLHttpRequest.js:570:25)
    at setState (/data/yug/projects_active/make-modules/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/xmlhttprequest/lib/XMLHttpRequest.js:593:14)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/data/yug/projects_active/make-modules/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/xmlhttprequest/lib/XMLHttpRequest.js:427:13)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at _stream_readable.js:943:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
```

**Is there any limitation to use `new` in nodejs ? How can I make it work both client and server side ?**

Comment: `Uint8Array` should work without a type error. What Node.js version are you in?

Comment: `node -v : v0.10.33`. My client side tests are with Chormium Version 39.0.2171.65 Ubuntu 14.04 (64-bit), which imply V8 js engine.

Comment: That seems like a tricky issue. Have you got any tests for the converter engine? It might be a good idea to check whether the function works independently.

Comment: The exact same function works fine in Google Chrome.

Comment: Well then, what about testing it separately on Node?

Comment: I don't understand how to do, where to start that. @__@

Comment: Just plain unit testing, here. Create another executable module, run the function with some inputs and verify the outputs.